# How can I make a development copy of my site in a subdirectory to test out a theme?

Tags: clone-site

I have purchased a WordPress theme and I want to test the theme on the same domain without removing the current theme.

For example:

- I have a WordPress website www.example.com (running with one theme)
- I want to install a new theme to www.example.com/new (with the new theme)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a development copy of the existing site by:

1. Copying all the existing files to the subdirectory.
2. Making a copy of the database and pointing to the database copy in the `/new/wp-config.php` file. You will need to change the options `homeurl` and `siteurl` in new database's `wp_options` table to add `/new/` to the end of it.
3. Login to the test site and install the theme and activate the theme to test it.

Alternatively there are staging plugins available that can do most or all of this process for you such as Duplicator and Sandbox.

Another possibility is to install the new theme on the existing site and test it with a tool such as [Theme Test Drive](http://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-test-drive/) plugin or [Toolbar Theme Switcher](https://github.com/Rarst/toolbar-theme-switcher). Usually you can configure the theme while testing it this way, but not always - it depends on how the theme saves it's settings.

Comment: Can I do the following?                                                                             step 1 - create a /new folder in my existing directory                               step 2 - create new database                                                                 step 3 - install wordpress in /new folder                                               step 4 - install my purchased theme

Comment: yes there is no problem with that - unless you have a page slug on your existing site called `new` in which case just use something else.